# Calling function recursively at regular intervals

Tags: node.js

So I was wondering what is a better way (in terms of stack growth and performance) to recursively call a function at regular intervals?
For example, lets say I want to read file contents every 200 ms. I have the following two methods and was wondering if they are any different?

Method 1: Using plain ols setTimeout without process.nextTick

```
var fs = require('fs');
(function loop() {
  // Print to time to indicate something is happening
  console.log(new Date().toString());

  // Read a 51MB file
  fs.readFile('./testfile', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });

  // Call the same function again
  setTimeout(function () {
    loop();
  }, 200);
})();
```

Method 2: Calling process.nextTick inside setTimeout

```
var fs = require('fs');
(function loop() {
  // Print to time to indicate something is happening
  console.log(new Date().toString());

  // Read a 51MB file
  fs.readFile('./testfile', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });

  // Call the same function again
  setTimeout(function () {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      loop();
    });
  }, 200);
})();
```

What I want to know is that adding process.nextTick inside setTimeout helps or not? Will calling the function inside process.nextTick will alleviate the stack usage or not?

Comment: Not to answer you, but you should definitely put the `setTimeout` in the callback of your `readFile`.

Comment: I don't see any recursive calls here. The call to loop is called when the timeout event happens, not from within the function. It can't be called until loop() returns

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no recursion in the following simplified example:

```
function test()
{
   console.trace();
   setTimeout(test, 1000);
}

test();
```

output (note that stack is not growing)

```
Trace
    at test (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/rec.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:312:12)
    at module.js:487:10
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:238:9)
Trace
    at Object.test [as _onTimeout] (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
Trace
    at Object.test [as _onTimeout] (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
Trace
    at Object.test [as _onTimeout] (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
Trace
    at Object.test [as _onTimeout] (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
Trace
    at Object.test [as _onTimeout] (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
Trace
    at Object.test [as _onTimeout] (/private/tmp/rec.js:3:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```