# node.js call stack exceeded on self recurring function

Tags: node.js, recursion

This code GETs URL, however my server could not handle 1k requests at same time so I made it reccuring as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115830/1368173), but it returns error below, why?

```
var http = require('http'),

    path = '/getter.php?id=';
    options = {
        host : 'localhost',
        port : 80,
        path : '/getter.php?id=',
        method : 'GET',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: true,
        agent: false
    },
    get = function (i, max, step, time) {
        for (i; i <= max; i++) {
            var handler = function (key) {
                http.request(options, function(res) {
                    console.log(key);
                }).end();
            };

            options.path = path + i;
        }

        setTimeout(get(i + step, max + step), time);
    };

get(0, 10, 10, 1000);
```

**ERROR:**

```
>node index.node.js

index.node.js:13
        get = function (i, max, step, time) {
                       ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the call that's causing the problem:

```
setTimeout(get(i + step, max + step), time);
```

It's because you're *calling* get, rather than setting it to be called later.

Instead, pass the function *and* arguments to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(get, time, i + step, max + step);
```

From the NodeJS [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg) (emphasis added):

> To schedule execution of a one-time callback after delay milliseconds.
>   Returns a timeoutObject for possible use with clearTimeout().
>   **Optionally you can also pass arguments to the callback.**